# How to use Jenkins credential store when accessing CVS?

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to use the credential store with the CVS plugin to access a CVS repository? Looking for a way to store credential once and have one place to change it, despite many jobs making use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CVS plugin doesn't use the credentials store directly (although there are potential plans to move to this in a future overhaul of the plugin), but it does have a concept of global credentials which should provide what you need. The reason for having something separate from global credentials was that CVS introduced this prior to the credentials plugin being available and the steps have never been taken to try and perform a migration.

To use this credential feature, ensure you have version 2.4 or above of the CVS plugin, goto your 'Manage Configuration' screen, scroll down to the CVS section and click the 'Add' button next to the 'Authentication' option. Once you've added any credentials in here, go back to the jobs you're wanting to use the global credentials on, check the CVS root matches what you put in the authentication section and that it doesn't contain a username and then run your job. When running, the console should then show 'Using globally configured credentials for...' when trying to connect to CVS.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Like so many answers, it seems like it was right before my nose but I missed it!

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again. This is confirmed working for a user who expects to have many jobs. Credentials must change every 6 months so it is nice to have just one place to make the change.